# Current/voltage relation in MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, semiconductors

I have the following problem:

[image]

I want to find the graphical current/voltage relationship for both the MOSFETs on the left. The only difference I can actually spot is the doping of the body of the MOSFETs. There's a slight increase in acceptor dopants in the MOSFET below. I'm not too sure how this would affect the graph. Any suggestions?

For the first MOSFET (with p-), I think we'll get a rough sketch of:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your plot is (qualitatively) valid in the near subthreshold region, V<sub>GS</sub> < V<sub>th</sub>.

The threshold voltage depends on the acceptor concentration in the substrate. For a heavier doped substrate, the threshold voltage V<sub>th</sub> of an n-type mosfet is higher. The current voltage formula for V<sub>DS</sub> ≥ (V<sub>GS</sub> – V<sub>th</sub>) and V<sub>GS</sub> < V<sub>th</sub> is
$$
i_D ≈ I_{D0}·exp\left({-{κ·(V_{th}-V_{GS}) - V_{BS})}\over{V_T}}\right)
$$
where V<sub>GS</sub> is the gate/source potential, V<sub>BS</sub> is the substrate (bulk/source) potential, κ is a "capacitance channel divider" coefficient C<sub>ox</sub>/(C<sub>ox</sub> + C<sub>D</sub>), C<sub>D</sub> is the depletion layer capacitance.

In principle, the depletion layer capacitance depends on the channel's acceptor concentration, so the subthreshold slope also changes. Pay attention: for a "classical" transistor layout (not tunneling, 3D nanowire or else) it is greater than 60 mV even with a lightly doped substrate, still more for a heavier doped substrate case.